# Probability of multiple events not occurring

Tags: probability

I have a question I have to do as part of an assignment, and I am unable to get any help from anyone at the minute and I was hoping someone could check if I'm on the right track and if not point me in the right direction.

This is not the question but it gets the idea across and I will be able to apply it to the real question.

After much experience checking the status of equipment in a workshop an engineer has worked out that for every item he is asked to examine there is $0.788$ chance of finding a major fault and there is $0.912$ chance of finding a minor fault.

What is the chance of finding that $4$ pieces of equipment have no fault at all?

So my thinking was if

$P(x)$ is any fault, $P(y)$ is minor fault, $P(z)$ is major

so $P(x) = P(y)\cup P(z)$

so $P\left(\overline{x}\right) = (1-P(x))$

that the probability of no fault at all

$P\left(\overline{x}\cap\overline{x}\cap\overline{x}\cap\overline{x}\right)=P\left(\overline{x}\right)^4$

Sorry if this is a little bit trivial, but I just need to make sure im doing the right thing.

Comment: That looks fine, assuming the parts have faults independently.

Comment: Your notation looks off.  If $P(y)$ is the probability of the event $y$ as having occurred... then you mean to write $P(y\cup z)$ not $P(y)\cup P(z)$.  Now, part of the difficulty with the problem as written is that we aren't told that $z$ is a subset of $y$, so we don't have enough information to find $P(x)$.  We further don't know if the existence of faults of whatever kind are independent of one another across different pieces of equipment, so we can't justify your last step.

Comment: Recall that $P(A\cup B)$ is not equal to $P(A)+P(B)$ unless $A$ and $B$ only happen simultaneously with probability zero.  Recall that $P(A\cap B)$ is not equal to $P(A)\times P(B)$ unless $A$ and $B$ are what we call independent events.

Comment: There is no information in the question
 I just am assuming that they are independent because of the level of maths we are working at,
yes I meant inside the brackets P(y∪z) 
it doesn't say it is a subset it just says one is a minor fault, one is a major fault, so I have taken it to mean 2 independent events.

Comment: I didn't notice the notation error with union but, basically, it's fine.